# Dev Express Extreme Grid - Add columns properties by IF condtions

Tags: c#, devexpress-mvc

Note: I've already put a ticket into Dev Express for help too.

We are making a control out of the dev extreme grid in MVC.

We are trying to add properties (more than just 1, 10 right now) to columns.Add() based on if conditions. In some cases we DO NOT WANT a sort order applied. With the way it is set up now, we are adding a SorOrder.Asc to all columns even though only ONE needs it. The property is set on the model for that specific column where the others do not have it at all, but it is being defaulted to ASC and causing the sort to be incorrect.

Just curious if someone else has dealt with this as well.

Here is the code:

```
            foreach (var item in Model.Columns)
            {
                column
                .Add()
                .SortOrder(item.SortOrder)
                .Visible(item.Visible)
            }
```

So I only want to put a sort order in IF that value isn't null. The probably is it will only accept SortOrder enum and that only has ASC and DESC.

So we are trying to put an IF condition and only add .SortOrder() if item.SortOrder is not null.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `if(item != null) column.Add().SortOrder(item.SortOrder); else column.Add();` what's wrong with this ?

Comment: @iSR5: but I need to add multiple Items. That will work if I only needed to do .SortOrder.  Sorry I should have said that.

Comment: not clear, but why you don't just check the enum and re-set it again based on the item.SortOrder. something like this `var _sort = item.SortOrder; if(_sort == null) _sort = _sort.DESC; column.Add().SortOrder(_sort).Visible(item.Visible);`